# In GCC, how to (temporarily) suppress messages from "#pragma message"

Tags: c++, gcc, build, compilation, pragma

I'm getting many messages emitted from `#pragma message` from the GLM library. Is there a way to suppress these, preferably temporarily (just for that library)?

Comment: I looked into gcc-4.9's info page, there does not seem to be a way to do this using compiler options.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can come up with is to pipe the output of `g++` through a filter, i.e.

```
g++ [args...] 2>&1 | filter_command
```

(which has the disadvantage of loosing the exit code of `g++`), or

```
g++ [args...] 2> >(filter_command)
```

(which works only if your shell is bash, not just plain POSIX sh, but it does carry the exit code).  The `filter_command` could e.g. be a `sed` script that deletes anything between a line matching `note: #pragma message:` and a line containing whitespace and a lone `^`:

```
g++ [args...] 2> >(sed '/ note: #pragma message: /,/^ *\^/d')
```

I'm not certain that that would catch all forms of `#pragma message` output, though.